# How to force D8 "Configuration synchronization" to send HTTPS download URL

Tags: 8, redirection, configuration

I have a Drupal 8 site hosted on an Apache Server.
There are 2 virtuals hosts :

- one listening on port 80, which redirects everything to HTTPS
- one listening on port 443 which serves the htdocs directory where the Drupal site is located

Everything works well, except for the "Configuration synchronization" full export. When I click the "Export" button, I'm redirected to the home page, without any message or log.

Enabling the console on my web browser, I saw these calls :

```
POST https://my.domain.fr/admin/config/development/configuration/full/export
[HTTP/1.1 303 See Other 86 ms]
GET http://my.domain.fr/admin/config/development/configuration/full/export-download
[HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently 101 ms]
GET https://my.domain.fr/
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 183 ms]
```

The download process of the config file seems to be *killed* by the redirection.

The second URL (GET http) is sent by Drupal in the response to the first call, in the "Location" header.

How can I force Drupal to send only HTTPS url, even in the Location header in this precise case ?

**Edit:** [Potentially linked post](https://www.drupal.org/node/2842049)

**Edit2:** I'm having the same trouble with the **RSS link** on the site : on the page returned by `https://my.domain.fr`, the RSS link is `http://my.domain.fr/rss.xml`

**Edit3:** Found the solution for the export problem (see answer below). Still not a solution for the RSS link, but it's not the main subject of this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot the `SSLEngine On` Apache directive in the configuration of the VHost listening on port 443.

With it, the Location header sent by Drupal contains now `https` scheme.